# Excel Min Max for each day by employee

Tags: excel, max, min

i have data that i would like to indicate the first and last time for each different day for each employee.  An example of my data is below, the column that i would like to put an indicator in is the FirstLastTrip Column

[Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TCA3.jpg)

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you tried?

Comment: Is your data always sorted by person then date ascending?

Comment: This is a site for programmers to find solutions to the problems they encounter. It isn't a site where non-programmers find programmers with spare time on their hands which they don't know what to do with. If you are a programmer, even a very new one, please post your code or formulas, show us where you are stuck, and someone will help you reach your goal.

Comment: yes the data is sorted in ascending date, but not always do the times line up in order, that is why i thought i would have to try using min and max

Comment: I'm sorry i am new to this level of formulas in excel, i tried for hours to get something to work, none of them were close, i didn't save them, if i need to ask for help again i will save my last attempt and include it as i didn't realize it was necessary, again i apologize i missed that step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(IF(C10="","",IF(C10=MIN(IF(($C$1:$C$16<>"")*(A10=$A$1:$A$16)*(B10=$B$1:$B$16),$C$1:$C$16)),"First",IF(C10=MAX(IF(($C$1:$C$16<>"")*(A10=$A$1:$A$16)*(B10=$B$1:$B$16),$C$1:$C$16)),"Last")))=FALSE,"",IF(C10="","",IF(C10=MIN(IF(($C$1:$C$16<>"")*(A10=$A$1:$A$16)*(B10=$B$1:$B$16),$C$1:$C$16)),"First",IF(C10=MAX(IF(($C$1:$C$16<>"")*(A10=$A$1:$A$16)*(B10=$B$1:$B$16),$C$1:$C$16)),"Last"))))
```

Please note that this is an array formula and that you have to confirm it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of only pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd>-key.
[image]